# How can I keep my UIGestureRecognizers from crashing?

Tags: ios, automatic-ref-counting, uigesturerecognizer

I'm having a really frustrating issue with UIGestureRecognizers. They get added fine, but whenever one gets triggered, it crashes with the message `EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0xf0000008)`. I'm adding it in the view controller using the following code:

```
- (void)handleDrag:(UIGestureRecognizer *)sender {
    NSLog(@"%@", sender);
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIPanGestureRecognizer *panGesture = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleDrag:)];
    [self.windowBar addGestureRecognizer:panGesture];
}
```

`self.windowBar` is a UIImageView. I've enabled user interaction on said UIImageView. But whenever I start actually dragging it, it crashes.

I'm not sure if this has anything to do with it, but I'm using the new ARC feature.

What else am I missing? :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try running with the Zombies Instrument to detect exactly which zombie (already released) object is being referenced.  It will point you to the exact object that the system thinks it should send a message to, but has already been released (with retain count set to 0, and the memory already reassigned).

Comment: I feel so stupid. :( I got so focused on the recognizer that I failed to ever check the view controller. Thanks for reminding me about Zombies though. :)